# What is the 'c' in "f(n) <= c g(n)"? How do you find it?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm having some trouble understanding the concept of 'c' in this statement. Do I need to find a specific c? Technically couldn't this statement be true always? Like if c is a million or something?

```
 Let f(n) and g(n) be functions from positive integers to positive reals.

 We say f = O(g) if there is a constant c > 0 such that f(n) <= c * g(n).


        f1(n) = n^2               O(n^2 )
        f2(n) = 2n + 20           O(n)

    which is better?

     f2(n)        2n + 20
    -------  =  -----------  <= 22
     f1(n)           n^2

         i.e. f2 = O(f1)

  if n is 1, then 22/1 ==> 22

  if n is 2, then 24/4 ==> 6

  if n is 3, then 26/9 ==> .. gets smaller

                    2
     f1(n)         n
    -------  =  ---------  <= ______ no such constant
     f2(n)       2n + 20

         i.e. f1 is NOT O(f2)
```

I don't understand where the 22 comes from. I understand it is f2(1)/f1(1), but I don't know why you need to look at that fraction. Where does the c value come from?

I am just struggling trying to understand the concept, and an explanation would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: all algorithms are more or less about math. Big O is something to evaluate algorithms.

Comment: You **don't** need to look at **that** fraction; but if you do then you can observe that for all n>0, (2n+20) <= 22 (n^2). The concept is just to "classify" functions, those which grow roughly one like others or not.

Comment: @Matthias: Fair enough.

Comment: You are allowed to leave out an initial segment of n values. The Landau notation in complexity is, after all, for asymptotic behavior for large values of n. So it is also possible to say that 

    20n+2 <= 22n<= n^2 for n>=22. 

This ties in with the limit definition of barenblats answer, and is also what I suspect the answer of vijar is about

Answer (score 1):

The definition you provide for big-O notation is incomplete, which, I suspect, has contributed to your difficulties.  A better definition comes from Ronald L. Graham, Donald E. Knuth, and Oren Patashnik, *Concrete Mathematics*, 2nd ed., Addison–Wesley (Upper Saddle River, NJ), 1994, p. 444 (§9.2):

> The formula
>
> > f(n) = O(g(n)) for all n
>
> means in this context that there is a constant C such that
>
> > |f(n)| ≤ C|g(n)| for all n […].

The key bit is the quantification – ‘for all n’.  Remember this for later.

Now, to answer your questions:

- If you are attempting to prove that ∀n : ℤ⁺. f(n) = O(g(n)), then you do not have to find a specific C – you need only prove that one exists.  Of course, the easiest way to prove that one exists is to provide it, so often, you will find yourself picking (or bounding) a C.
- The statement cannot always be true, even if you pick an absurdly large value for C.  For example, ∃C : ℝ. ∀n : ℤ⁺. |n²| > C|n|, and this means that n² ≠ O(n).
- In the provided example, the 22 is the constant.  The authors sought to prove that f₂ = O(f₁), or that ∃C : ℝ. ∀n : ℤ⁺. |f₂(n)| ≤ C|f₁(n)|.  They did so by rearranging the latter relation to |f₂(n)| ∕ |f₁(n)| ≤ C, asserting that C = 22, and then showing that the relation holds.

If you’re struggling with big-O notation, don’t feel alone – it’s a topic that pretty much every computer scientist has grappled with at least once.  To ease the difficulty somewhat, Eric Lehman, F. Thomson Leighton, and Albert R. Meyer, in their book [*Mathematics for Computer Science*](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/), unpublished, 2010, p. 276 (§9.7.2), present an alternative, limit-based definition, which was much easier for me to get a handle on:

> Given nonnegative functions f, g : ℝ → ℝ, we say that
>
> > f = O(g)
>
> iff
>
> > lim sup[x→∞] f(x) ∕ g(x) < ∞.

This definition is precisely equivalent to the one in *Concrete Mathematics*, but it dispenses with the difficulty of finding a constant and replaces it with the difficulty of taking a limit, which is much more familiar territory for new computer scientists.

Comment: You might want to add back in the variables that got stripped when you pasted.

Comment: Yeah, I can't understand this without the variables!

Comment: Apparently, it's a Chromium bug: [Issue 109844](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109844). They are displayed properly in Firefox and IE.

Comment: I’ve replaced the Unicode mathematical alphanumeric symbols with other code points.  _sigh_  The day will come when we have beautiful math in the browser, but it is not this day.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very valid Q to understand the performance of algorithms.

I would suggest you an exercise. Draw the graphs for f1, and f2.

You will see at some point f1 will intersect f2 and after the intersection point, you will see that f1 will dominate i.e f1 will be above f2. So in terms of algorithm, for all input of length (where n < c), f1 will give better performance and for n > c, f2 will give a better performance.

Comment: You are using the constant `c` in a completely different role than how it was used in the question, which can be confusing. The `c` in the question is a multiplication factor and not a minimum value for `n`.

Comment: Fair enough. f = O(g) defines that f is one of functions from the set of functions of g such that f(n) <= c* g(n). For all c = 1..21, f cannot be strictly < g(n). For evidence, check for n = 1 for all c = 1..21. At n = 22, f = g and for c > 22. f2 < 22*f1. However, I agree there is no closed form equation to solve to get the value of c. However, just by brute force, one can find that for c >= 22, f2 =  O(f1)